# Cloudflare SSL origin certificate not working on wordpress Ubuntu

Tags: server, apache2, ssl, wordpress

I have installed Pem and key files in `/etc/cloudflare` directors and when I insert virtual block 443 in my `/sites-available/000-default.conf` file the apache server fails to restart successfully. I have tried configuring the same in sites-available/default-ssl.conf file too, but without success. I thought the apachectl configtest sends syntax OK.

The image of the apache error logs is given below.

[image]